# I have Deployed My Django App in apache server . All the static files are getting served properly but its not accepting media files from Form Input

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, ubuntu-16.04, web-deployment

While Submitting a form having media input its showing

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/django/media/pictures'
```

I have searched in google but no one told giving permissions for media files , they ever all telling about static files only . Can any one please tell me which permission i have to give to it with chmod no.

Answer (score 0):

You're having permissions issues. To fix it, you need to allow the Apache process access to the folder and it's content.

This can be done through the following steps

1. Change the permissions to read and write

   ```
   chmod 664 /home/ubuntu/django/media/pictures -R
   ```
2. Give the group Apache runs under (www-data group) group ownership of the folder and its content

   ```
   sudo chown -R :www-data ~/home/ubuntu/django/media/pictures
   ```
3. Restart the Apache service

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

If you want to ensure Django behaves as it should, you can also add the following to your settings.py

```
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = 0o755
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```