# Unable to add an image in Django Admin page hosted on EC2 with Apache2 server

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2

I am learning Django deployment on EC2 with Apache server. I am able to serve static files. But when I try to add an image via Admin page, I am getting below error.

[image]

The permissions for media_root is as below

[image]

I am able to add image with Django server inside the instance, but with Apache server I am getting error.

Apache2 is configured as below

```
    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/testing/dummy/static_root/
    Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/testing/dummy/media_root/


    <Directory /home/ubuntu/testing/dummy/static_root>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/testing/dummy/media_root>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/testing/dummy/dummywebsite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/testing/dummy/dummywebsite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess loserprocess python-home=/home/ubuntu/testing/testingenv python-path=/home/ubuntu/testing/dummy:/home/ubuntu/testing/testingenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/
    WSGIProcessGroup loserprocess

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

I have given the permission as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61518637/16139714), but still I am facing issue.

Can you please let me know what I am missing here.
Thanks